# then(function) not getting updated with returned promise value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to to get some data from API with the help of promises in angularjs. I have one service which is getting a value from API and returning the promise to controller.

```
***Service***
this.forgotPasswordLink = function(email){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/forgotPassword',{
        email: email 
    }).success(function(response){
        console.log("the new response is: ",response);
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }).error(function(error){
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

**Controller**
authService.forgotPasswordLink($scope.forgotPasswordEmail).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.message === 'emailFound'){
            $scope.emailSent = true;
            $scope.emailNotSent = false;
        }
        else{
            $scope.emailNotSent = true;
            $scope.emailSent = false;
        }
    });
```

Here authservice is the name of the service . so this code is working fine but the problem is when I try to get data multiple times one after the other, for the first time promise is returning the correct data but when I try to post with different data, promise doesn't updates the then(function) even though promise gets proper response from server.

if you see there are two console statements, one in service and one in controller; so the console statement in controller is getting executed first as promise is returning the old value and when promise is resolving, second console statement which is in service is executed with the updated value.

So how do I get the updated value in then(function). do I need to refresh the service after posting the data once.

Comment: I believe `.post()` is returns a promise natively, so there is no need to create a new deferred object. Also, you should use `.then()` as a success handler, not `.success`. You can simply use `return $http.post(...)` without actually chaining any methods, since you'll be evaluating the promise in your controller.

Comment: are you sure http request not returning error response ?

Comment: Are you saying that invoking `authService.forgotPasswordLink("email1")` and then `authService.forgotPasswordLink("email2")` returns the same result?

Comment: @NewDev I am getting the correct response and correct values from the server and even promise is able to resolve the new values but the problem is when promise is returned to controller, .then(function) is not getting updated with the new value!

Comment: @Yash, if you are resolving with the right value, then this is the value that the `.then` handler will get. Either you missed something in your debugging, or the code above does not repro the issue

Answer (score 0):

As @Terry suggested, you don't have to depend on $q at all, to achieve the result. I recommend one of the following two approaches:

**#1:**

```
***Service***
this.forgotPasswordLink = function(email){
    return $http.post('/forgotPassword',{
        email: email 
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log("the new response is: ",response);
        return response;
    }).catch(function(error){
        return error;
    });
};
```

In this case, the controller remains the same; only thing to note is that, even in error case, the controller's then function will be called with `data` being the error object returning from catch block of service.

**#2:**

```
***Service***
this.forgotPasswordLink = function(email){
    return $http.post('/forgotPassword',{
        email: email 
    });
};

***Controller***
authService.forgotPasswordLink().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if(data.message === 'emailFound'){
        $scope.emailSent = true;
        $scope.emailNotSent = false;
    }
    else{
        $scope.emailNotSent = true;
        $scope.emailSent = false;
    }
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error); // Error handling like notifying user, etc...
});
```

In the second approach, the service just returns the promise returned by `$http`. The controller then takes actions based on the result of this promise.

One can argue that it's the service's duty to obtain the data and give it to controller to take actions. This is the first approach.

I personally prefer the first approach, since the service is simple and it's easy to test this way.

Answer (score -1):

When you use then method you have put .data after your variable so data.data.